# Freeze first column in igGrid

Tags: iggrid

Using ([igGrid](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2019.1/ui.iggrid)), is there a way to make a column always in the first position?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqQjO.png)

My current config:

```
{
    "primaryKey": "ID",
    "height": "70vh",
    "autoGenerateColumns": false,
    "requestType": "POST",
    "autoCommit": true,
    "dataSourceType": "json",
    "responseDataKey": "data",
    "showHeaders": true,
    "fixedHeaders": true,
    "enableHoverStyles": false,
    "features": [
    {
        "name": "ColumnFixing",
        "fixingDirection": "left",
        "columnSettings": [
        {
            "columnKey": "check",
            "allowFixing": false,
            "isFixed": true
        },
        {
            "columnKey": "ID",
            "allowFixing": false,
            "isFixed": false
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "ColumnMoving",
        "columnMovingDialogContainment": "window",
        "movingDialogWidth": 300,
        "columnSettings": [
        {
            "columnKey": "check",
            "allowMoving": false
        },
        {
            "columnKey": "ID",
            "allowMoving": false
        }]
    }]
}
```

My current config keep the first column fixed, by I can move other columns, fixing them in the first position. How to avoid that?